# html column handling in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a requirement to send email from oracle code.

Email id , subject and body of the email is formatted in the oracle query. The body of the email is a simple hyperlink as follows.

```
https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0&caseID=011
```

caseId is dynamic and the where clause in the query accepts dynamic case id's

My query looks like,

```
select
'a@abc.com' email,
'Welcome back !' subject,
'<a href="https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0&caseID='||c.case_id||'">https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0&caseID='||c.case_id||'</a>' body
from cases c where c.case_id = 011;
```

Output is:

```
<a href="https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0011="011>"https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0011="011</a>
```

Expected Output is:

```
<a href="https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0&caseID=011">https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0&caseID=011</a>
```

Can someone help find out why the caseId is replaced with number (011="011) instead of caseID=011
I am messing with quotes I guess but unable to find out.

Comment: Some tools will treat `&caseID` as a substitution variable named `caseID` (perhaps that's your *caseId is dynamic and the where clause in the query accepts dynamic case ids*) so if that's the case it would be helpful to include the value provided.

Answer (score 1):

Output you claim to be is ... wrong. Where did the first double quotes go?

```
SQL> with cases (case_id) as
  2    (select '011' from dual)
  3  select
  4  '<a href="https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0&caseID='||c.case_id||'">https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0&caseID='||c.case_id||'</a>' body
  5  from cases c where c.case_id = '011';

BODY
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<a href="https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0&caseID=011">https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0&caseID=011</a>

SQL>
```

---

Your "expected output" (above) vs. my output (below): there's **no difference**, so - why do you think that there's something wrong?

```
<a href="https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0&caseID=011">https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0&caseID=011</a>
<a href="https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0&caseID=011">https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0&caseID=011</a>
```

This is what I see after executing your sql: BTW i am using sqlDeveloper

```
<a href="https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0011=011">https://www.example.net/ind/case/viewIndCase.action?submitType=0011=011</a>
```

Comment: I am still getting the same

Comment: The same ... what? I'm not sure I understand what you want, because your "expected output" seems to be wrong, while mine seems to be OK. At least, I don't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: I have made couple edits. I had replaced with your query but still see 0011=011"

Comment: I edited my answer as well, adding comparison between your expected output and my result. No difference.

Comment: I have added what I see to your reply above.

Comment: Did you run my code, **exactly** as I wrote it, or did you run yours? Because, in SQL Developer, I see the same result as in SQL*Plus (as expected).

Comment: OK this is what helps : '||'&'||' - Thank you so much

Comment: Hm, strange ... I don't need it, you do. How come? Anyway, I'm glad you made it work! You're welcome.

Comment: I dont know for some reason it ddnt work without '||'&'||' Thank you